# how to keep my navigation drawer always on top of everything? ANDROID

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to keep my navigation bar on top of everything or overlay or overlap on everything in my activity?

I have this code in my main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have now is that my tablayout will show all the time even I have show my navigation drawer. Anyone know how to help me with this?

Your answer will be appreciated.

[image: this is the screen shot of my current situation]

Can you see that the tablayout is still there even if I have my navigation drawer show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `NavigationDrawer` to be on top of everything else, your `DrawerLayout` must be the parent layout for all your views.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: hey @MohanadMohie once I changed the DrawerLayout become the parent, and my whole tablayout become to full screen

Comment: You can adjust the `LinearLayout`'s size and its contents as you wish, as long as the `DrawerLayout` is the parent of the whole layout.

Comment: okay i will give it a try first, android xml really make me headache compare to html

Comment: Ok, and if it works for you, don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Cheers.

Comment: oh man. it works like a charm. really appreciate ur help. really dont know much about android XML. btw, may i ask u a question? we cant add any linearlayout or relativelayout to the listview?

Comment: The ListView is a view that carries a list of similar views, so its children are added automatically from the code (adapter). You can put the ListView inside a Linear/RelativeLayout and add any other views with it together with your ListView inside the layout.

Comment: but i have tried putting the ListView inside the LinearLayout and the whole thing is running away

Comment: You probably didn't give it `android:layout_gravity="start"` and remove it from the ListView, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the **TabLayout** Inside Drawer Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="#FFF"/>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```